# iOS; Swift; How do I keep an annotation open even when the screen is tapped within a MapBox map view?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have my screen split; 50% for the map and 50% for a list of elements. As the list of elements is scroll, the annotation will pop around the map based off whichever element is in the top of the list. This part is working fine.

However, when the user taps on the map, I don't want the annotation to disappear. I really want the user's tap to interactive with the MapView instead of the AnnotationView.

Is this possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can intercept the built-in tap gesture recognizer or add a [custom tap gesture recognizer](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.4.1/gesture-recognizers.html). When the user taps the map, check if an annotation is selected. If one is selected, call [mapView:selectAnnotation:](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.4.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)selectAnnotation:animated:) to keep it selected.
2. You can call `mapView:selectAnnotation:` in the relevant `mapView:deselectAnnotation:` or `mapView:deselectAnnotationView:` [delegate method](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.4.1/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/Selecting%20Annotations).

Comment: I have been looking up how to do just that, but I am running into dead ends. When the map is loaded, I set the selected annotation, which loads an annotation view. The annotation view is capturing the tap, and I am not sure how to add a tap gesture recognizer to the annotation view. Any help with how to add the gesture recognizer to the annotation view would be great. Thanks.